# Do you know any example when space complexity is O (n log(n))

Tags: allocation, space-complexity

Do you know any example when space complexity is O (n log(n))

I just started to learn algorithms and I wasn't able to find the answer.

Comment: This should probably go on [cs.se]

Comment: The worst case condition for a skip list has space complexity of O (n log(n)). Look up `skip list`

Answer (score 0):

A [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) has (worst case) space complexity of O(n log n)

There is a good summary of algorithms and datastructures and their space/time complexity at http://bigocheatsheet.com/